# JNI FindClass format for subclasses?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

What is the correct FindClass identifier syntax to load subclasses? For example:

```
package a.b.c;

class Foo {
   class Bar {
     ...
   }
}
```

To get `Foo` I can do `(*env)->FindClass(env, "/a/b/c/Foo")`, but trying to get `Bar` through `(*env)->FindClass(env, "a/b/c/Foo/Bar")` throws a `ClassNotFoundException`. Is there a different syntax for representing subclasses?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Never mind, the `javap` tool proved helpful here. The correct syntax is:

`a/b/c/Foo$Bar`

Comment: That's a general principle. You should always use `javap`, rather than trying to figure it out. JNI method and type signatures are another example where `javap` knows the correct answer.

Comment: Except in this case I'm trying to do it while transforming arbitrary code, so launching `javap` and trying to match up the outputs wouldn't exactly work.

Comment: I don't understand that. Is there more to your question than you asked?

Comment: The point of the question was to discover the general syntax for these identifiers so I can create them while walking the parse tree. Running javap on every file and trying to match up the signatures would be cumbersome at best, so I was looking for a "formula" for the identifier, excluding anonymous classes. It seems to be "pa.cka.ge.Outer$Middle$Inner".

Comment: Also note that for non-static nested classes (inner classes), the constructor takes an additional argument of the outer class making the signature not what it seems. In this example it would be "(La/b/c/Foo;)V". Of course javap is helpful in debugging this as well :)